# Loading a CSV file and creating new class Instances from the values

Tags: java, csv

I have a class defined like this, with the appropriate getter and setter methods...

```
public class Album {
    private int id;
    private String artist;
    private String name;
    private int published;
}
```

I also have a .csv file that stores this content for a number of Albums. In the file, one line represents one Album.

I'm trying to read the information from the .csv file, and then use the setters of the `Album` class to assign the values. Here is my code...

```
public Map<Integer, Album> load() {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileName);
    Map<Integer, Album> loadedAlbums = new HashMap<Integer, Album>();

    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        Album album = new Album();

        String[] albumDivided = scanner.nextLine().split(","); 
        //in the .csv file every unit of information is divided by a comma.

        album.setId(Integer.parseInt(albumDivided[0])); //this is line 11.
        album.setArtist(albumDivided[1]);
        album.setName(albumDivided[2]);
        album.setPublished(Integer.parseInt(albumDivided[3]));

        loadedAlbums.put(album.getId(), album);

    }

    return loadedAlbums;
}
```

However, trying to use this code, I get the following Exception:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "albums.csv" at line 11.

Could you please help me to understand the cause of this problem.

Comment: Oh and the format of information in the file is: "1.,Artist Name,Album name,Published"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem is described to you by the Exception...

A `NumberFormatException` would have been triggered by one of your `Integer.parseInt()` lines. The line of your code that is triggering the exception is *Line 11* (as per the exception message) - not sure which one this is but its probably the first `Integer.parseInt()` line.

Your code is trying to convert the value *"albums.csv"* to a number, which is obviously isn't. So somewhere in your CSV file you must have a line that contains the value *albums.csv* where it is expecting a number.

Hope this helps pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I realized the problem now.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want the whole solution here is a hint to resolve your problem:

You should take a look at the [API documentation of the Scanner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.String%29). Take a really close look on the constructor that expects a single String parameter (as you use it in your code).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Gotta study the API more carefully in the future

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, albumDivided[0] will containt "1." which will not be able to parse to an integer because of the dot. Either remove the dot from your csv file, or create a new string that removes the dot before you parse it to Integer. The approach might look something like this:

```
String newString;
for(int i=0;i<albumDivided[0].length-1;i++){ //length -1 to remove the dot
   newString = newString + albumDivided[0].charAt(i); //get the string stored in albumDivided[0] and add each char to the new string
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will keep this in mind if I encounter problems with this.